# How to filter a powerapps gallery based on previous screen

Tags: sharepoint, filter, powerapps

I'm trying to create an powerapps app for audits. These audits have multiple questions and I want to create a screen where the user can awnser multiple questions in 1 screen. But all questions have to be linked to the audit. So if a question is already filled in it will display the awnser and is able to edit this if needed. 
Every question needs to get a grade (1-10) and a description of the awnser.

I already have a detail screen for the audit itself with the base information. idealy i want a button that can go to the questions and fill them in. I'm using multiple sharepoint databases to store the information. So i would like to store the awnsers here as wel. For the awnsers i made a seperate database linked to the audit and the question.
I also have a database for the information of the audit and one for all the questions.

So my question is how do filter a gallery based on the audittitle? and also how do i save this information easily in the sharepoint envoirment

Comment: Could you post some screenshots, will be helpful.


Try below
Set the Items property of the Gallery control to following formula:
Filter(audits,title=titleValue))

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots could have clarified the problem in a better way, but as much as I could understand from the problem subject, here is a solution to "how-to-filter-a-powerapps-gallery-based-on-previous-screen" :

1. When you have lots of fields in previous screen which is required for filtering.
   You can store the values on previous screen either in a sharepoint list (by submitting the forms from previous screen ) and then fetching them to filter content ( by having a gallery inside a gallery)

OR

2. When you have less number of fields.
   You can simply store the values in variables by using Set(a,box1.text)  ((where a is the variable name and box1 is the input box) function on navigation to new page ( by putting this in Onselect menu) and then using it in the filter command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to filter a gallery from the value coming from previous page.

- put a button on the screen from where you want the value
- on select property of the button put this code

> Navigate(screenName,screenTransition,{variableName:valueToFilter})

- Now on the Items property of Gallery put below code

> Filter(datasource,columnToFilter = variableName)

Note that this variableName should be the same as above.

This will filter out your data in gallery. 
For your 2nd question:

- Create a list in Sharepoint which will have all the questions/fields.
- Connect this list to your PowerApps app
- insert a form on a screen.
- add your Sharepoint list as a data source to the form
- insert the button on the same page as form

  - onSelect property of button put this code

> SubmitForm(formName)